# python pandas how to organize similar group data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to organize similar group data. Here is my data frame

```
  SKU
FATUT
GUYGE
FATUT-01
SUPAU
GUYPE
SUPAU-01 
FATUT-02
GUYGE-01
```

my expected dataframe will be look like this:

```
     SKU
   FATUT
FATUT-01
FATUT-02
   GUYGE
GUYGE-01
   SUPAU
SUPAU-01
   GUYPE
```

I want to organize similar group of data sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `groupby` with the parameter `sort=False`; then concatenate the split DataFrames.

How it works:

- Group `df` by the strings before the dash
- `groupby` sorts by the groupby keys by default; when we specify `sort=False`, we make sure that the keys are stored in the same order as they first appear in `df`, i.e. "GUYPE" stays behind "SUPAU".
- `groupby` object contains information about the groups that you can unpack like a dictionary. Then unpack it and build a generator expression that returns the grouped DataFrames.
- Using `concat`, concatenate the split DataFrames into one; by using `ignore_index=True`, we ignore index coming from the split DataFrames and reset the index.

```py
out = pd.concat((d for _, d in df.groupby(df['SKU'].str.split('-').str[0], sort=False)), ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```py
        SKU
0     FATUT
1  FATUT-01
2  FATUT-02
3     GUYGE
4  GUYGE-01
5     SUPAU
6  SUPAU-01
7     GUYPE
```

But I feel like, for your task, `sort_values` might work as well, even if the orders are not exactly the same as in the desired output:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by='SKU', ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```py
        SKU
0     FATUT
1  FATUT-01
2  FATUT-02
3     GUYGE
4  GUYGE-01
5     GUYPE
6     SUPAU
7  SUPAU-01
```

Comment: thanks for your help. `df.sort_values` is very easy to understand but can you please explain little bit your `out` variable code. So we can understand how it's working.

Comment: @enke thanks a looooot man. Your explanation of code helping me lot to understand the concept.